# Is there a way to disable the HTTP -> HTTPS redirect on the Umbraco backoffice/admin interface?

Tags: umbraco

I have umbraco running on an AWS instance where the load balancer sends traffic to web users via HTTPS but all internal communication is HTTP.

I have no power with respect to the server config, so I am unable to use the admin interface since visiting the /umbraco path results in too many redirects.

Is there a way to disable the http to https redirect on the umbraco backend?

I can't seem to find a setting which forces a secure connection under the /umbraco route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a setting in web.config called umbracoUseSsl - if not, maybe try creating it and set it to false? https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/Security/

Comment: thank you! this was indeed the solution. I was looking under urlRewriting.config and other areas of web config. I hadn't thought to look in the appsettings.  Hindsight is obvious of course :)